# Routing on local LAN with SSL

Tags: iis, networking, proxy, dns

We have multiple QA machines on our local LAN that run different sites, each machine on a different version:

QA1 runs `test1.167.company.com`, `test2.167.company.com`
QA2 runs `test1.168.company.com`, `test2.168.company.com`

We recently added SSL to these sites.
To avoid using using multiple certificates, and because of the max 1 wild card in a certificate we're using `*.company.com` on all these sites. Therefore, we've changed the URLs for these sites from
`<tenant>.<version>.company.com` to `<tenant>-<version>.company.com`.

example: `test1-168.company.com`

Now, we have a problem with DNS routing. Assume we have 1000 sites on each machine - test1 - test1000.
We were not able to create a rule based on the version part of the subdomain. So we need to create a record for each of these sites individually to route to the correct machine (ip).
We cannot use a subdomain for the version, because then we'll need a new certificate for each version.

I tried looking into proxy/reverse-proxy, but couldn't find a solution that considers **part** of the subdomain.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Example summary:
I need
`*-167.company.com` to be routed locally to QA1 (10.163.128.1) and
`*-168.company.com` to be routed locally to QA2 (10.163.128.2)

Comment: If the URL to be rewritten is not in the same domain, you cannot use URL rewriting. You can use URL redirection instead of URL rewriting, or you can use the reverse proxy function in IIS.

Comment: @DingPeng I've added an example summary to the question. Can you elaborate on the solution?